# Force Pillow to generate an image with the TrueColor type, while I only use black and white

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, rgb, image-formats

I generate images using **Python 3.6.6** and **Pillow==5.3.0**. All images have 'JPEG' format and 'RGB' color mode.

When I make an image with colors, it will come out with `Type: TrueColor` (and with Channel depth: red: 8-bit green: 8-bit blue: 8-bit)

When I only use black and white, it will come out with `Type: Grayscale` (and with Channel depth: gray: 8-bit)

Since I try to use a printing service that only accepts my colored images, I want to try to to make the black/white images a `TrueColor` image, even though they will not have any other (RGB) colors in them. 
Can I simply do this?
Or does a `TrueColor` image means that the RGB values cannot be all 0?

I don't see how I can do this in Pillow. My preferred way is to enforce this when I generate the image in my Python code.

An alternative could be to convert the image with a tool (I am on Ubuntu 18.04, and I use ImageMagick and ffmpeg). I tried the following, but it did not seem to do anything. The output file has the same metadata as the original.

```
convert -type TrueColor original_file.jpeg converted_file.jpeg
convert -type TrueColor -depth 8 original_file.jpeg converted_file.jpeg
```

## EDIT & Example

Here is Python code to create two images, with the same mode (RGB).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (230, 25, 75)

def draw_line(file_name, line_color):
    """
    Draw a 400x400 image with a white background and one 
    diagonal line of the given 'line_color'
    """
    image = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(400, 400), color=white)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.line(xy=((100, 100), (300, 300)), fill=line_color, width=5)
    image.save(fp=file_name, format='JPEG')

draw_line(file_name='black_line.jpeg', line_color=black
draw_line(file_name='red_line.jpeg', line_color=red)
```

The image with the black line will have `Type: Grayscale`, and the one with the red line `Type: TrueColor`. 
Note that the ColorSpace is sRGB in both cases, and the depth is 8-bit.

```
identify black_line.jpeg
black_line.jpeg JPEG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5.12KB 0.000u 0:00.000

identify -verbose black_line.jpeg
  Type: Grayscale
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 8-bit


identify red_line.jpeg
red_line.jpeg JPEG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5.26KB 0.000u 0:00.000

identify -verbose red_line.jpeg
  Type: TrueColor
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
```

So my question is: can I create images with Pillow so that, regardless what colors I use, they always come out as the same `type: TrueColor` with the 3 channels? So even in the case where I draw a black line on a white background.

(NOTE: when I draw a red line with the default width of 1, it will have `Type: Palette` instead of `TrueColor`)

### Attempt to convert to TrueColor

```
convert black_line.jpeg -type truecolor black_line_tc.jpeg
identify -verbose black_line_tc.jpeg |grep Type
  Type: Grayscale
```

So it will not convert the type to TrueColor.
I made a diff of the identify outputs, but there is no relevant difference regarding the channel_depth/colorspace/type etc., so I will not post the output.

```
identify -verbose black_line.jpeg > identity_black.txt
identify -verbose black_line_tc.jpeg > identity_black_tc.txt
diff identity_black.txt identity_black_tc.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps using Python wand, which is based upon ImageMagick will help. If your output is PNG, then set it to PNG24:ouputimage.png. If your output is some other format such as tif or perhaps jpg, try adding the equivalent of -type truecolor. Sorry, I know ImageMagick, but not wand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I first try to figure it out in Python/Pillow, and if that is not going to work I will have a look at Wand.
ps. I am using jpeg now. Do you think it will be easier if I switch to png?

Comment: PNG needs it to be done one way. JPG needs it to be done another way. I do not know if Pillow supports either way. Sorry, I do not know Pillow.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. In the tests below:

- `BW-RGB.jpg` is a greyscale plasma image (with RGB channels) exported from Gimp
- `BW-Grey.jpg` is the same image in pure greyscale (one channel) exported from Gimp

IM's `identify` says:

```
BW-Grey.jpg JPEG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 48.2KB 0.010u 0:00.000
BW-RGB.jpg JPEG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 49.1KB 0.010u 0:00.019
```

And if I use:

```
convert BW-Grey.jpg -type TrueColor  BW-Converted.jpg
```

IM's `identify` says:

```
BW-Converted.jpg JPEG 400x400 400x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 54.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

So the result is indeed RGB. Note that the size of the RGB and greyscale files isn't very different, which is expected. A color image is saved as three frames, a B&W one and two chroma ones, but for a greyscale image (R=G=B) these two chroma images have one single uniform value and so compress very well.

PS: On Linux you can confirm IM's `identify` report using the `file` command: it reports one frame in greyscale images, and three in color ones.

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to do it in ImageMagick. But the OP wants to do it in Python Pillow. I am not sure Pillow supports such a feature. But I suspect that Python Wand does, since it is based upon ImageMagick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question with new info. My grayscale image has `Colorspace: sRGB` and `Channel depth: gray: 8-bit`. So the difference with your answer is that your BW-grey.jpg did not have the `Colorspace: sRGB`.

So maybe I can try to generate my black and white image in a different mode so that it will have this Colorspace: Grey. (like the image in your example). And then I might be able to convert it correctly to sRGB.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

I have been experimenting with this and it seems very uncontrollable - by me at least!

I tried adding some random red, green and blue single pixels to your image here and there but it doesn't seem to result in the type changing to TrueColour any time soon.

I then tried adding and subtracting a tiny amount of random noise to all pixels and made some progress, but the image gets *"perceptibly unhappy"* before ImageMagick acknowledges it is TrueColour. Suppressing subsampling in the JPEG encoder and increasing the quality help a little - but not much.

I found I had to increase `N` (the noise amount) to 9 before ImageMagick agreed the image was TrueColour. You may want to experiment so here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

def makeTrueColour(image):
   """
   Force image to TrueColour by 'slightly distorting' greys.
   Distortion means adding a tiny random amount of noise (0-N) to pixels that will not
   "burn out" (i.e. exceed 255) as a result, and also subtracting a similar tiny 
   random amount of noise from pixels  from pixels that will not underflow as a result.
   If N=1, this means less than 0.4% error - hopefully imperceptible.
   """

   N = 1
   w, h = image.size
   ni = np.array(image)

   # Mask of pixels that will not exceed 255 by adding N
   okpix = (ni <= (255 - N))
   # Make additive noise in those pixels
   noise = np.random.randint(0,N+1,size=(h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8) * okpix
   ni += noise

   # Mask of pixels big enough to subtract N
   okpix = (ni >= N)
   # Make subtractive noise in those pixels
   noise = np.random.randint(0,N+1,size=(h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8) * okpix
   ni -= noise

   return(Image.fromarray(ni))


image = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(400, 400), color=(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.line(xy=((100, 100), (300, 300)), fill=(0,0,0), width=5)

tc = makeTrueColour(image)
tc.save('result.jpg',subsample=0,quality=95)  

# This just counts the unique colours in "tc" - you don't need it
T = np.array(tc)   
print(len(np.unique(T.reshape(-1, T.shape[2]), axis=0)) )
```

**Original Answer**

I am not sure I understand. Here's what I get when I make an RGB image:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make a fully black image
im = np.zeros([480,640,3], dtype=np.uint8) 

# Save as RGB
Image.fromarray(im).save('resultRGB.jpg')

# Save as greyscale
Image.fromarray(grey).convert('L').save('resultGRAY.jpg')
```

Now I look at those with **ImageMagick** and get exactly what I expect:

```
identify result*jpg

resultGRAY.jpg JPEG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 3932B 0.000u 0:00.000
resultRGB.jpg JPEG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5427B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

What were you hoping for? Please click `edit` under your original question and give a counter-example.

Comment: Mark, I think what he wants is a grayscale image that will be identified by other software as RGB with 3 equal channels.

Comment: @fmw42 But that is what he gets if he saves a 3-channel image, like my black one above that I save as `result.RGB.jpg`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misread your code. But some tools may read a grayscale (not just all black) image as grayscale and not RGB. I think it depends upon the tool and the file format (JPG, TIFF, PNG, etc). One should really not use IM identify, but rather check with exiftool, since IM makes assumptions from the data to interpret the type/class.

Comment: `@MarkS` Your example likely works since you started by creating a 3 channel black image from bumpy. What happens if you start by creating a grayscale (black to white) gradient in PIL. Does it show as grayscale or RGB. Perhaps PIL knows to make it RGB, if you specify 3 channels to your gradient else it becomes Grayscale if you specify only one channel when creating the gradient. I have posted an example that shows how it works in ImageMagick using identify -verbose and exiftool to check the number of channels and colorspace and bits per channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question, I hope the question is clear.

So I want to end up with an Image that has only one black line on a white background, and that has Colorspace sRGB, Type: TrueColor and the 3 rgb channels.
I'm not sure if that even makes sense, but I am trying to understand how these things work. Preferably I would like that every output I create has the same format/type/colorspace etc.

Comment: As a last resort add one color pixel in one of the corners of the image. That will make it colorspace RGB with type truecolor

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, Actually that was the first thing I tried and, surprisingly, it did not result in a TrueColor image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of forcing a single channel grayscale JPG image to 3 channel colorspace sRGB image using ImageMagick.

Here I create a grayscale gradient. Then use Imagemagick identify -verbose and it shows as colorspace Gray. Exiftool confirms that as 1 channel (color component) with 8-bits.

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient: grad.jpg

identify -verbose grad.jpg
Image: grad.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 8-bit
...

exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D grad.jpg
...
    - BitsPerSample                   : 8
    - ColorComponents                 : 1
...
```

Now I use -type truecolor to convert the grayscale image to colorspace RGB. ImageMagick says colorspace RGB and so does exiftool showing it is 3 channels (color components) each of 8-bits.

```
convert grad.jpg -type truecolor grad_tc.jpg

Fredericks-Mac-mini:desktop fred$ identify -verbose grad_tc.jpg
Image: grad_tc.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
...

exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D grad_tc.jpg
...
    - BitsPerSample                   : 8
    - ColorComponents                 : 3
...
```

I suspect that PIL defines the colorspace by how many channels you use when reading or creating the image. Sorry, I am not that familiar with PIL. But if it does not, then you might be able to pass it to numpy to make it 3 channels. Then bring it back to PIL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I updated my question. 
My grayscale image has `Colorspace: sRGB` and `Channel depth: gray: 8-bit`. Your gray image has `Colorspace: grey`. And your conversion works fine (to 3 channels in sRGB) while the conversion for me does not work.
So I think I should try now to generate my grayscale images with `Colorspace: Gray` instead of sRGB, and then I might be able to succesfully convert them.
(another difference is that I use the .jpeg extension, while you use .jpg)

Comment: If your grayscale image has colorspace sRGB, then is that not what you wanted?  Using JPG vs JPEG should not matter.

Comment: Well, I just noted the `Type` / `Channel depth` differences, and that is where my question arose if I can get the same values for that for any picture.

So the printing service uploader accepted my sRGB Truecolor image but not the sRGB Grayscale image. So I thought I should try to get 3 channels for the picture with just black and white lines as well.